VfUnescapeEl rule for SelectOptions Value in apex:repeat used in Javascript on Visualforce page
I have SelectOptions variable objectFieldTypes in Apex Class, I bound certain values in this variable. I am using this in Javascript on Visualforce Page Like this
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val2type = new Array();
   <apex:repeat value="{!objectFieldTypes}" var="f">
       val2type['{!JSINHTMLENCODE(f.value)}'] = '{!JSINHTMLENCODE(f.label)}';
   </apex:repeat>
</script>

My code is working fine, but when I am running Salesforce security scan I am getting VfUnescapeEl Rule error on
<apex:repeat value="{!objectFieldTypes}" var="f">

This is Managed package visualforce page in which i used this.

You should be using JSENCODE rather than JSINHTMLENCODE. The difference is that the former is used in a script tag, while the latter is used in an event attribute.
Note also that you can generate the array more efficiently by using array notation:
<script type="text/javascript">
  var val2type = [
  <apex:repeat value="{!objectFieldTypes}" var="f">
    '{!JSENCODE(f.value)}': '{!JSENCODE(f.label)}',
  </apex:repeat>
  ]
</script>

JSINHTMLENCODE is used when you have an inline script:
<button onclick="alert('{!JSINHTMLENCODE(message)}')">Click me!</button>


Issue i am getting on this line
<apex:repeat value="{!objectFieldTypes}" var="f">
how can i encode this objectFieldTypes, because when i am running security scan i am getting VfUnescapeEl Rule error on above Line.
